# Why do I create a new model object in two methods in a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, crud

Following various parts of the internet, I have the following code:

**Controller**

```
class StudiesController < ApplicationController

    def new
        require_user
        @study = Study.new
    end

    def create
        @study = Study.new(study_params)
        if @study.save
            flash[:success] = "You made it!"
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            flash[:danger] = "Uh oh—something went wrong"
            redirect_to study_path
        end
    end
end
```

**View**

```
<%= form_for(@study, url: {action: :create}, class: "study-form") do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %><br>
    <div class="btn-submit">
        <%= f.submit "I studied today!", class: "btn btn-primary margin-top" %>
    </div>
<%= end %>
```

It works, but my question is: Why do I need `Study.new` called twice? Why do I call it in `create` if I've already called it in `new`?

Comment: Try removing the `url: {action: :create}`, you don't need that. aswell as the `=` on the end function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instance of Study that is created in the new method is used in the view to render HTML.

When that HTML is sent to the browser, the instance of Study no longer exists -- it was never saved, and was created just to help render the HTML.

When a form is submitted from the browser, parameters are passed in to assign values to the instance that is to be created, but first a new instance of Study must be created to assign them to.

This instance is then saved.

Comment: According to my understanding, the only thing the form does is: 1) Create parameters such as `{study: {title: "hello"} }`, 2) `POST` to the controller's `create` method with those params. Is that true? Or does the form do more?

Comment: That's pretty much correct, but adding those items onto the HTML form is done via the view, which use an initialised object to do so.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using Study.new in the new method to create a new object, it is used to create a new record before saving and to render a new form. After that when you are using Study.new(study_params) in a create method it will built object from values submitted by the form and the data will be saved in the database table.